# Cannot run with sound null safety because dependencies vibration to nullsafety

Tags: android, flutter, button, slider, dart-null-safety

After installing

```
dependencies:
  slider_button: ^2.0.0
```

It showing the null safety error I checked the slider_button package the null safety is integrated. How can i resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved as i checked the slider button package. There is the vibration version which is not moved to null safety. I first added the vibration package of null safety then slider button like this.

```
  vibration: ^1.7.4-nullsafety.
  slider_button: ^2.0.0
```